# CocoaPods - dylib causes invalid swift support error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using this CocoaPods library https://cocoapods.org/pods/dlib, and it builds .dylib with header files, which is not wrapper in .framework. It runs fine on iPhone, but can't be submitted to iTunes Connect, because .dylib must be wrapper in .framework. Is there an easy way to wrap it in .framework and keep using CocoaPods?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you find a solution?